# svn up does not work

Tags: svn

If I have a file `a.cpp` from the respository, and for testing purpose, I delete a line from this file. After doing an svn up, I get a message that I am at the latest revision, but the deleted line is not added back. I am using svn from Macintosh command line terminal. Does this sound like an svn bug?

Answer (score 4):

The `update` subcommand brings changes from the repository into your working copy. It doesn't destroy uncommitted local changes:

```
C:\>svn help update
update (up): Bring changes from the repository into the working copy.
```

You want the `revert` subcommand:

```
C:\>svn help revert
revert: Restore pristine working copy file (undo most local edits).
```

See [Version control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/index.html) for further details.

Comment: I want to merge files from a "folder" into my repository. I have replaced files in the repos with the files with fixes from the folder.. but since I replaced them I lost the changes which were committed in the repos. Could you please point to a possible solution?

Comment: I can't understand a word, but feel free to ask a question about that.

Comment: I have a "folder" which I want to merge with my repos. I replaced the file a.cpp from "folder" (which has a fix, but is old) with the one in repos. Now, how can I add changes made in repos (after a.cpp was checked out into the "folder")?